# How to access element of array of hash reference in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

```
my @arrH = (
    { 'name' => 'getTapsArmPTDetailPl_sp', 'type' => 'P ' },
    { 'name' => 'getTapsFRPTDetailPl_sp',  'type' => 'P ' }
);

my $arRef = \@arrH;
```

I would like to print each element..

Comment: Use Dumper from Data::Dumper it its for logging.

Comment: anywhere you want to use `@arrH` you can use `@{$arRef}`

Answer (score 3):

```
use feature 'say';
for (@arrH) {
    say for values %$_;
}
```

Or if by "element" you mean key and value:

```
for (@arrH) {
    while (my ($k, $v) = each %$_) {
        say join " => ", $k, $v;
    }
}
```

Or if you just want to see what is inside your data structure:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@arrH;
```